# Display number of posts from a certain category?

Tags: wordpress, loops, categories, posts

How can I display ONLY the number of posts from a certain category ?
I want to display only the number without the category name.

I used this code

```
wp_list_categories('show_count=1&include=23&title_li=');
```

but it displays the category.

Any help please ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would help you to read this => http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-number-of-posts-per-category

> 

```
function number_postpercat($idcat) {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "SELECT count FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE term_id = $idcat";
    $num = $wpdb->get_col($query);
    echo $num[0];
```

}